# Trouble with custom react component

Tags: react-native

Having a go at making my first react native component. I am trying to build a component that reverses the strings passed to it. It works perfectly fine when I give it a hard coded string, but it dosen't seem to do anything when I pass it a string from a "TextInput" component.

Here is what I think are the relevant bit of code.

```
class ReverseText extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: props.src};
}

reverseString = (str) =>{
    let newString = "";
    for (let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        newString += str[i];
    }
    return newString;
};

render() {
    let display = this.reverseString(this.state.text);
    return (
        <Text>{display}</Text>
    );
}
}

export default class PizzaTranslator extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{padding: 10}}>
            <TextInput
                style={{height: 40}}
                placeholder="Type here to translate2!"
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}/>
            <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
                {/*{this.state.text.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' ')}*/}
                {this.state.text} /* this works */
            </Text>
            <ReverseText src="123" /> /* this works */
            <ReverseText src={this.state.text} /> /* this dosen't works */
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

Why does the component work when I pass it a hard coded string, but fails when I pass it a string that I get from the TextInput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class ReverseText are just setting the state at first time receive the *this.props.src*. So, when you change the *this.props*, nothing happen.

To fix you could do this:

```
export default class ReverseText extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {reverseText: ''};
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        this.setState({reverseText: this.reverseString(nextProps.src)})
    }

    reverseString = (str) =>{
        let newString = "";
        for (let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            newString += str[i];
        }
        return newString;
    };

    render() {
        return (
                <Text>{this.state.reverseText}</Text>
        );
    }
  }
```

Comment: So is "componentWillReceiveProps" like a life cycle method that gets called every time a new prop is sent to the component ?

Comment: Yes, it is. It&#39;s will change the reverse text whenever the input text change.

Comment: Nice. Must not have reached that part of the tutorials yet.